# Duvida passagem de paramentro em Java

Tags: java

Fala pessoal,

estou com duvida no seguinte método:

```
 /**
     * Metodo x
     */
public Exit Method(String n) {
    final Ent y = new Ent();
    y.setn(n);
    Exit res = OpUtil.Envia(new Job() {
        @Override
        public Exit run(OpInt oi) throws RemoteException {
            Exit res = oi.execute(y);
            if (OpUtil.Ok(res)) {
                //...
            }
            return res;
        }

        @Override
        public ExitList runAsList(OpInt oi)
                throws RemoteException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    });
    return res;
}
```

O método OpUtil.Envia recebe apenas um objeto do tipo Job como argumento, qual o comportamento da aplicação nesse caso - quando abro um "{}" e chamo outros métodos?

Poderiam me ajudar com exemplos pfv.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O seu método `OpUtil.Envia` esta recebendo um objeto do tipo `Job` com dois métodos [sobrescritos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) (`run` e `runAsList`).

Isto significa que se estes dois métodos de Job forem invocados, em algum momento, pelo método Envia, eles vão reagir da forma que foram implementados quando foram passados como argumento, ao invés de reagirem como foram implementados na classe original.

Um exemplo simples, que ilustra bem a mesma situação:

```
    public class Mensagem {
        public Mensagem() {}

        public void enviarMsg() {
            System.out.println("Mensagem enviada pelo método original");
        }
    }
```

Classe principal para testes:

```
   public class Principal {

        import Mensagem;

        public static void main(String[] args) {

              //Criando uma instância de Mensagem normalmente
              Mensagem objeto = new Mensagem();

              //Criando uma instância de Mensagem com o método
              //enviarMsg() sobrescrito
              Mensagem objetoSobrescrito = new Mensagem() {
                    @Override
                    public void enviarMsg() {
                        System.out.println("Agora a mensagem é enviada pelo método sobrescrito!");
                    }
              };

              //Testando os resultados
              objeto.enviarMsg();
              objetoSobrescrito.enviarMsg();
        }
   }
```

Saída de dados:

> Mensagem enviada pelo método original 
>   Agora a mensagem é enviada pelo método sobrescrito!

Comment: Muuitoo Obrigado!. Saberia me dizer o nome desse recurso?

Comment: São classes anonimas, @Filipe. [Se precisar...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)